# Create a grand Average in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a line chart which will show the comparison of a locations clients compared to the companies average clients.  Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this link:

https://www.credera.com/blog/business-intelligence/tableau-workaround-part-3-add-total-labels-to-stacked-bar-chart/

The trick is you create a second line chart that holds the overall average line and then you combine them as a dual axis chart.

So whatever your measure is duplicate it, add a table calculation to it by right clicking and select "Moving Average". Then combine the charts by right clicking on the axis of the second one and select dual axis. This will overlap the two charts so you have a total avg line and lines for the individual locations.

Comment: Thanks,  I was hoping there was a better way- but I ended up doing it in the raw data.